# Add new index in the middle of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I know that I can remove something in the middle of an array such as

```
char* cArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeTracker);
```

using the `memmove` function. In this way something will be removed from the array without having to use a temp array, switching to vectors, etc. The question here is that can I add a new index in the middle of the array (is there a function for it)? Or let's say that using `realloc` I add a new index at the end, then how can I move the values down efficiently?

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain why you downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote but above code is all about C while it is tagged C++ - I'd suspect that could be a reason for the downvote.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: the difference between C and C++ is technically support for object orientation. Do you expect the code not to work in C++?

Comment: You tagged the question as C++ so why malloc and not new? Secondly arrays are static, inserting into them requires room at the end so that elements can be moved (regardless if there is or not any ready made function for that). And lastly you should really use std::vector for this task that will handle it for you (provided you actually are using C++).

Comment: @Resurrection: "Secondly arrays are static"! Who says so? You have not heard about dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: I did not downvote.  To clarify,  by "add new index in middle of array" do you mean "insert an element within the array"?   (which is trivial using C++ std::vector).

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: No, the concept behind this question is to avoid for loop or any kind of loop, similar to the `memmove` function. just for the sake of education and performance. To clarify, imagine the "InsetAt" method in C#.

Comment: If you are doing this perhaps a linked list would be better datastructure

Comment: @Arrrr: if you don't want to know potential answers to your questions, don't ask! You asked why there was a downvote and shared a reason. Although the C++ community isn't as offended to C code as the the C community seems to be about seeing C++ code, there seems to be some expectation that questions tagged C++ use reasonably idiomatic C++ approaches.

Comment: This is a C++ question asking how you'd do something in C++ that the OP alreadys knows how to do in C. Perfectly sesnible to post C code in this case!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I'm exactly looking for what I asked, if you think this impossible, I will later prove you wrong. Done this before when I decided to create classes on the fly in C# and I did it (just for education). Many said impossible though. Your answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Arrrr: I didn't claim it is impossible. All I said that there is no ready made question for it. Also, I think my answer is providing all the necessary tools to implement *exactly* what you asked for. It is lacking the actual code to do so but using the functions mentioned that should be a trivial matter of just using them. What exactly is missing from my answer other than the exact code?

Comment: @Arrrr You should perhaps learn about C/C++ arrays first. Arrays are static. Dynamic allocation has nothing to do with it. In order to change the size of an array you need to allocate a new one and copy the old array to the new location that is bigger or smaller and destroy the old one. Whether you perform this on the stack or on the heap is irrelevant, the process is the same. And once again, vector will do this for you (and in all likelihood better, i.e. faster and safer).

Comment: @Arrrr - Note that this C approach you posted will not work at all for non-POD C++ objects.  Try to use `malloc` if that array were of `std::string` or another similar type instead of `char`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The problem with your approach that it is in conflict with the objective of the question. Meaning that I don't want to copy from an array to another or using a temp array at all. I just want to tweak the memory in way that a new block will be added "Somewhere" in existing allocated blocks of memory as array. Not sure if I explained it well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: you must be joking if you think my point is to recreate String type.

Comment: @Arrrr - What I am saying is that your approach is a non-starter if the array were of non-POD types.  It has nothing to do with creating a string type.

Comment: @Resurrection: An array means a sequence of memory block allowing for a collection. It can either have a fixed size or dynamic size.

Comment: @Arrrr Not in a sense you want. Dynamic means the size is not known at compile time NOT that it can change its size on the fly. Once an array is allocated (regardless of how, where and when) its size is fixed. There will be memory used by other things before it and after it. If you somehow forced it to expand beyond the allocated bounds it would then be undefined behaviour. You would override something else's memory. To expand existing array you need to allocate new one.

Comment: Memory is physically organized in blocks. You can insert a block of memory between two other blocks. Since this does affect the memory map I think you'd need access to the operating systems memory map which is unlikely to be accessible. Entities which not a multiple of blocks won't be able to be inserted into the middle of an entity. I'd be interested in seeing how it is done if you prove me wrong :)

Comment: The interface of `realloc()` does look as if it could be used to expand memory at the end of the currently allocated memory: it doesn't necessarily return a new address but could just arrange for more memory to be available at the end of the segment. Whether any actual implementation even tries to do so is questionable (it is rare that there are sufficiently few memory allocations that the following page isn't used, yet) and even if it does, the interface does not allow injecting into a middle of a buffer.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yeah solving puzzle is what I get paid for :D. You know there easy ways to solve this problem, but I'm not interested in those. I wanna find about something I never knew, or in other words me and you don't know yet. So I'm working on it.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `std::deque<...>` or a different block-oriented structure where the memory of the actual entities can stay put while the data structure takes care of managing pointers to the blocks.

Comment: @Arrrr your question is too vague at the moment. You say "something". Can you clarify whether you are just talking about an array of `char` storing characters.  Or are you using an array of char to simulate the storage of larger logical objects. If so, give details.

Comment: `realloc` does not "add a new index at the end", it increases the size of the array. There are no indices associated with this sort of array, just a set of contiguous `char`s.  The organization of data within that space is entirely up to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alternative Answer

I have been thinking about this and the comments where @DietmarKühl started talking about inserting blocks like a deque does.  The problem with this is that a deque is a linked list of blocks so then you can't start with an array.  if you start with an array and then want to insert something in the middle you have to do something else and I think I have an idea - it isn't fleshed out very much so it may not work but I will share it anyway.  Please leave comments telling me what you think of the idea.

If you had an array of items and then want to add an item into the middle all you really want to do is add a block and update the mapping.  The mapping is the thing that makes it all work - but it slows down access because you need to check the mapping before every access of the array.

The mapping would be a binary tree.  It would start empty but the nodes would contain a value: if the index you want is < the value you traverse the left pointer and if it is >= you traverse the right pointer.

So, an example:

Before the insert:

```
root -> (array[100000], offset: 0)
```

After the insert at 5000:

```
root -> {value: 5000,
         left:  (array[100000], offset: 0),
         right: {value: 5001,
                 left:  (newarray[10], offset: -5000),
                 right: (array[100000], offset: 1),
                }
        }
```

I have used blocks of 10 here - newarray is 10 in size.  If you just randomly insert indexes all over the place the block size should be 1 but if you insert groups of consecutive indexes having a blovk size larger than 1 would be good.  It really depends on your usage pattern...

When you check index 7000 you check the root node: 7000 is >= 5000 so you follow the right pointer: 7000 is >= 5001 so you follow the right pointer: it points to the original array with an offset of 1 so you access array[index+offset].

When you check index 700 you check the root node: 700 is < 5000 so you follow the left pointer: it points to the original array with an offset of 0 so you access array[index+offset].

When you check index 5000 you check the root node: 5000 is >= 5000 so you follow the right pointer: 5000 is < 5001 so you follow the left pointer: it points to the new array with an offset of -5000 so you access newarray[index+offset].

Of course optimizations to this would be really important to make this useful - you would have to balance the tree after each insert because otherwise the right side would be much much longer than the left side.

The downside to this is that accesses to the array are now O(log inserts) instead of O(1) so if there are lots of inserts you will want to realloc every so often to compact the data structure back to an array but you could save that for an opportune time.

Like I said it isn't very fleshed out so it may not work in practice but I hope it is worth sharing anyway.

## Original Answer

If you have a C style array and want to insert an index in the middle you would need to either have an array larger than you need (plus a variable like sizeTracker to keep track of the size).

Then if there was room left you could just memmove the last half of the array out one to create a spot in the middle.

If there wasn't any room left you could malloc another whole array that includes extra space and then memmove the first half and memmove the second half separately leaving a gap.

If you want to make the malloc amortized constant time you need to double the size of the array each time you reallocate it.  The memmove becomes one machine instruction on x86 but even then it will still be O(n) because of moving every value.

But performance isn't any worse then your deleting trick - if you can delete everywhere throughout the array the cost is O(n) for that as well because you memmove half the values in average when you delete.

Comment: Good workaround. However you use alternative data structure to store inserted elements while OP wanted to directly insert elements into an array without copying it. From the discussion it is clear OP wants to manipulate the raw memory to expand the array in place... yeah.

Answer (score 1):

There is no custom C function which allows to increase an array using the C memory function and inserting an object into the middle. Essentially you'd build the functionality using `malloc()`, `free()`, `memmove()` (when enough space is available and elements are just moved back within the memory), or `memcpy()` (if you need to allocate new memory and you want to avoid first copying and then moving the tail).

In C++ where object locations tend to matter you'd obviously use `std::copy()`, `std::reverse_copy()` and/or `std::move()` (both forms thereof) as there may be relevant structors for the respect objects. Most likely you'd also obtain memory different, e.g., using `operator new()` and/or an allocator if you really travel in terms of raw memory.

The fun implementation of the actual insertion (assuming there is enough space for another element) is using `std::rotate()` to construct the last element and then shuffle elements:

```
 void insert(T* array, std::size_t size, T const& value) {
     // precodition: array points to at least size+1 elements
     new(array + size) T(value);
     std::rotate(array, array + size, array + size + 1);
 }
```

Of course, this doesn't avoid potentially unnecessarily shuffling elements when the array needs to be relocated. In that case it more effective to allocate new memory and move the initial objects to the start, add the newly inserted element, move the trailing objects to the location right past the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this post as C++.

> can I add a new index in the middle of the array (is there a function
>   for it)

No.  From cppreference.com, std::array:

> std::array is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays.

I interpret this to mean you can change the elements, but not the indexes.

---

(sigh) But I suspect C style arrays are still allowed. 
And I notice Dietmar's answer also says no.

Comment: OP is clearly not asking about `std::array`.  (There are several ways of making an array in C++)

Comment: @M.M - Thanks for the comment.  IMHO - the only C++ array is a std::array.  The 'other ways' (i.e. built in or "C-style array" or ?) are 'available' for backward compatibility and to support deferring conversion efforts.  In contrast to built-in,  the std::array: does not decay to T* automatically, and combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc.  C++ membership is not 'achieved' simply because your favorite compiler supports the older styles.

Comment: In programming in general, arrays may be resizeable.  "Array" is a concept characterized by storing several elements, usually of the same type. There are several different implementations of varieties of that in Standard C++ and many more ways that aren't part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using manually allocated memory you have to [reallocate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/?kw=realloc%22reallocate%22) and you should hope this operation does not move the memory block to a new location. Then the best is to use the [rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/?kw=rotate) algorithm.

By the way, prefer stl containers such as vectors to manually allocated memory for this kind of tasks. If you are using vectors you should have reserved memory.